# setTimeout with multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I tried to have a setTimeout function on multiple li items which have ul and li again. The slide animation works fine, but I want to have a delay before closing slideUp again. But it doesn´t work. The slide goes down but not up again. I think it is because I have to have a indexed setTimeout function for every li ul (indexed). But I have no idea how to get it work. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

```
var menu = $('#menu').find('li').has('ul'); 
var timer;
menu.on('mouseenter', function(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  $(this).find('>ul').stop().slideDown();                       
});

menu.on('mouseleave', function(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).find('>ul').stop().slideUp();
  },1000);
});
```

Comment: Why do you do `$('#menu').find('li').has('ul')` look up twice? Store it in a variable or use chaining.

Comment: This was just for a better overview. Changed it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have multiple lis, they will cancel out the open ones. You need to either assign the timeout to each li or you need to see if their is another li open to close it.

```
var lis = $('#menu').find('li').has('ul');

lis.on('mouseenter', function(){
    var li = $(this);
    var timer = li.data("timer");    
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).find('>ul').stop().slideDown();                         
});

lis.on('mouseleave', function(){
    var li = $(this);
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).find('>ul').stop().slideUp();
        },1000);
    li.data("timer", timer);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is absolutly logical. I tried your solution with assigning the timeout value to the lis. But it does not work. For any reason the timer value isn´t stored within the li element(s).

Comment: Ok got it :-) had to define timer as string as the data function of jquery requires a string. Thank you very much epascarello!!!